# Composing StandardScaler with a custom transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a custom transformer:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from datetime import datetime

class DayOfYearTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self  # nothing else to do
    def transform(self, X):
        date_array = X['date']
        day_of_year = [datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date().timetuple().tm_yday for date_str in date_array]
        return np.c_[X.copy().drop(columns=['date']), day_of_year]
```

It converts a date string into the day of the year, i.e., a number between 1 and 365.  Here is my pipeline:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

num_attribs = []
cat_attribs = ['country', 'store', 'product']
date_attribs = ['date']

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs),
    ("date", DayOfYearTransformer(), date_attribs),
])

merch_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(merch)
```

I want to apply an *sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler* transform to the output of

```
    ("date", DayOfYearTransformer(), date_attribs),
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two using a pipline that first does your `DayOfYearTransformer` followed by a `StandardScaler`. In code that reads like

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs),
    ("date", make_pipeline(DayOfYearTransformer(), StandardScaler()), date_attribs),
])
```

where I have used the convenience function [make_pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) to build a sklearn Pipeline object.